# Set a default component for Html Elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been playing with reactjs a bit lately. As I understand, ReactJS will convert html elements into something like this:

```
<div><span>Text</span></div>
```

Into

```
React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement('span', null, 'Text'))
```

So far so good, but what I'd like to do is have special component that will override all html elements so some kind of basic behavior can be added to any html element using props.

So instead of the above, I'd want something like this instead:

```
React.createElement(Html('div'), null, React.createElement(Html('span'), null, 'Text'))
```

This would make it possible to make usual html a bit more dynamic without having to define a new component each time. One alternative in my mind to this would be to have Component based on the props. So adding a particular prop would give a particular trait to the component above.

One example would be to have something like this:

```
<div foreach="collection" as="value">
   <div my-value="value" />
</div>
```

Just to explain a bit further, the idea is mainly to adapt React to different templating engines. So it's not necessary to rewrite completely templates to work in React and gives some kind of compatibility layer between a legacy templating engine.

So rewriting as this isn't what I'm asking. I already know how to write directly for React.

```
<div>
  {
    this.collection.map((value) => {
      return <div>{value}</div>
    })
  }
</div>
```

One alternative for me which would be quite easy if React can't do that easily is to transform the html elements as Uppercase or differently so React thinks it's a component instead of html.

Comment: What would that `Html` function return?

Comment: It would return a component.